# Cannot find the Hive Database path

Tags: hive

```
hive> set hive.metastore.warehouse.dir;
hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=/user/hive/warehouse.
```

Shows me the path being the /USER/hive/warehouse   but when I go physically and check for the same , it doesnt exists. Am I missing anything ??

Comment: Can you try with `/apps/hive/warehouse.`

Answer (score 0):

/user/hive/warehouse is actually your HDFS directory.
You can see by `hdfs dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse`